# Replacing a broken image and resizing the error image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

OK so I know this question has been asked separetly but I'm trying to use javascript to replace a broken image with another image with DIFFERENT dimensions by changing th `src` attribute. Here's a part of my code:

**MARKUP:**

```
...
<img id="error-img" class="img-header" onerror="imgError(this);" alt="Header" src="images/header.png">
...
```

**STYLES:**

```
...
.img-header { width: 54px; height: 64px; }
...
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
...
function imgError(image) {
image.onerror = "";
image.src = "/images/broken.png";
return true;
}
...
```

So what I need is to include a piece of code in this function so that when the image gets replaced the new image has it's dimensions set correctly but not 54x64px.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the answers guys but I've forgot to mention the size of the `broken.png` image:
Width: 276px Height: 45px.

Comment: So replace the values in below answer with those values and it will work...

Comment: Yeah I know I just wanted to help future visitors understand the question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can use `image.style` to set a width or height, or `image.className` to assign it a class.

```
...
function imgError(image) {
image.onerror = "";
image.src = "/images/broken.png";
// set width/height
image.style.width = "50px";
image.style.height = "50px";
// or add class name
image.className = "img-error";
return true;
}
...
```

CSS

```
...
.img-header { width: 54px; height: 64px; }
.img-error  { width: 40px; height: 40px; }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want replacement image to have it's own width/height and not inherited from `.image-header` class, you have couple options:

1). clear className:

```
image.className = '';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gGP5D/

2). add new class name:

```
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/images/broken.png";
    image.className += ' replacement-image';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gGP5D/1/

This new class name could define new dimensions if they are known, or reset width and height to `auto` values.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, as I already added the answer to change class name much earlier than you, why did you add one more answer targeting the same property/solution?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it, just saw that you propose changing `style.width`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to reset the image's CSS properties to whatever size your error image is:

```
function imgError(image) {
  image.onerror = "";
  image.src = "/images/broken.png";
  elem.style.width = "100px"; //use whatever size the new image is here
  elem.style.height= "100px"; //use whatever size the new image is here
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You can use `elem.style` - you need to change to `image.style`